# Filter an object to get values also in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object and an array

```
 {
    "library_items": 
    [

    {
        "id": "23493",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Physics Lecture",
        "authors": [{
                    "name": "Don Johnson",
                    "artifactID": "",
                    "role": "author",
                    "roleID": ""
                    }],
        "artifactType": "games",
        "domain":   {
                    "branch": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "branchInfo": {
                                    "branch": "",
                                    "subject": "Physics"
                                }
                    },
        "type": {
                "description": "",
                "id": "",
                "name": ""
        }
    },


   {
        "id": "23493",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Chemistry Lecture",
        "authors": [{
                    "name": "Don Johnson",
                    "artifactID": "",
                    "role": "author",
                    "roleID": ""
                    }],
        "artifactType": "games",
        "domain":   {
                    "branch": "",
                    "description": "",
                    "branchInfo": {
                                    "branch": "",
                                    "subject": "Chemistry"
                                }
                    },
        "type": {
                "description": "",
                "id": "",
                "name": ""
        }
    }
    ]
  }
```

I have another array

```
  var subjects = ['Physics', 'Biology', 'Mathematics']
```

how do I filter the Object using the array values in "subjects"?. I mean I want to get items from the object which have subject corresponding to any of the array values.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, making use of `filter` and `indexOf` methods.

1. **`filter`** Make use of this method to filter the array as per the matching criteria as defined in the callback function.
2. **`indexOf`** To check if the Array contains a value.
   **Note:** There is another method `includes` which can check for existence of an element in an array, which is part of ES7 draft but it is not supported by many browsers.

```js
var items = {
 "library_items": 
    [
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Physics Basics",
        "subject": "Physics"

    },
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Chemistry Basics",
        "subject": "Chemistry"

    }

    ]
};
var subjects = ['Physics', 'Biology', 'Mathematics'];
var filtered = items.library_items.filter((x) => subjects.indexOf(x.subject) > -1);
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I edited the code and I created a nested object...cn I still use you method above to get the value of "subject" in domain > branchInfo? or how can I adjust it

Comment: Yes, just replace the `x.subject ` with `x.domain.branchInfo.subject`

Comment: Yea I know..but I am thinking about a situation where the subject could be anywhere in the object tree. I do not know the structure of the object I should expect but I do know for sure that there is a "subject"

Comment: is there a way to scan through the entire object to find "subject"?

Comment: in that case, you need to `map` the Array so that you can atleast transform the array where you can query the object.

Comment: Yes, You can scan the Object recursively for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134631/discussion-between-charles-okojie-and-agalo).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var items = { library_items: [{ id: "23453", artifactID: "", title: "Physics Basics", subject: "Physics" }, { id: "23453", artifactID: "", title:"Chemistry Basics", subject: "Chemistry" }] },
    subjects = ['Physics', 'Biology', 'Mathematics'],
    filtered = items.library_items.filter(x => subjects.includes(x.subject));

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use lodash (https://lodash.com/docs) in every project. They have build a massive array of methods and wrappers that will make your live much easier.

```
 var items = {
 "library_items": 
    [
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Physics Basics",
        "subject": "Physics"

    },
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Chemistry Basics",
        "subject": "Biology"

    }

    ]
};
var subjects = ['Physics', 'Physics', 'Mathematics'];
_.find(items["library_items"], function(o) { 
  return subjects.indexOf(o.subject) > -1; 
 });
```

If you do not want to install additional packages I'd go with Agalo's answer!

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important to you. I would suggest another approach to you.

With filter and indexOf(or includes) your performance of the algorithm is O(n*m). For each library item you need to go through each subject.

If you create a simple hash table from subjects array first you can archive O(n+m). First, you go through each subject and write it to the hash table then for each library item you can check with O(1)(because of the hash table) whether you need that item.

Here is the code example:

```js
var items = {
 "library_items": 
    [
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Physics Basics",
        "subject": "Physics"

    },
    {
        "id": "23453",
        "artifactID": "",
        "title":"Chemistry Basics",
        "subject": "Chemistry"

    }

    ]
};
var subjects = ['Physics', 'Biology', 'Mathematics'];
var allSubjects = {};
subjects.forEach(s => allSubjects[s] = true);
var filtered = items.library_items.filter(x => allSubjects[x.subject]);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 result = obj.library_items.filter(o => subjects.indexOf(o.subject) > -1)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem. Currently, this answer isn’t even correct.